# WebView doesn't shrink to fit the height of the page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I've been using a `WebView` to load different data (HTML data) and it's all working fine. But the problem comes when the `WebView` refuse to shrink when he I load a smaller page. The WebView's height is set to `WRAP_CONTENT`.

I tried a lot of things like clearing the history (maybe a page from the history is stucking him in this size), tried to set is height to 0 and then again to `WRAP_CONTENT` before every page change and tried to use `clearView()` but this destroys the WebView totally.

Anyway, this is my code for loading:

```
// Clearing the web view
mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
mWebView.loadData(mItem.getHtml(), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WebViews don't wrap to the content of the html being shown because they go through layout before the content of the webview is loaded. WebView content is generally dynamic, so it wouldn't make sense to wrap like this.

If you're only trying to style text with HTML, you can actually use a textview for this.

```
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: I can't use `Html.fromHtml()` because I also have pictures there and css and WebView is my best option. How can I wrap the content anyway? It's kinda funny that I load a long text for let's say 1000 lines and then a text with 100 lines and the user must scroll through a large white space to get to the controls below the WebView. Is there any other option for doing it?

Comment: Well, I can think of a couple of possible approaches. If the controls below the webview aren't large, you could keep them onscreen, and just have the webview portion be scrollable.  You could also interact with some custom Javascript via addJavascriptInterface() that reports the height of the rendered page, then resize your webview accordingly.

Comment: I can't change the design, I must keep them below the web view.
I don't know a lot of java script, if you can write me a little example it will be great!